# Can a "Cont r a" post-process the result of its continuation

Tags: haskell, monads, continuations

the `Cont r a` type stands for a function which takes a continuation `a->r` and produces a result of type `r`. So both the continuation and the entire `Cont r a` produce a result of the same *type* `r`.

My question is: are the two results necessarily the same *value*, or can a `Cont r a` post-process the result from the continuation and produce a different value, albeit of the same type `r`?

I tried using `(+1)` for post-processing (note the `+ 1 --<--`):

```
c1 :: Int -> Cont r Int
c1 x = let y = 2*x
       in cont $  \k -> (k y)  + 1 --<--
```

Now that doesn't typecheck, because my post-processing function `(+1)` only accepts an argument whose type belongs to the `Num` typeclass. However, I pass the result of the continuation `(k y)` which is of some type `r` that is not guaranteed to belong to the `Num` typeclass.

Whatever I do to `(k y)`, it must be a function of type `r->r`. The only function which can do this for all `r` is the `id` function and using `id` for post-processing is no post-processing at all.

However, the whole thing does typecheck if I restrict `r` to the `Num` typeclass or even to the concrete type `Int`. It then produces the expected result:

```
*Main> runCont (c1 1) id
3
```

I am quite unsure,

- if such post-processing and restricting the type of `r` is a normal thing to do, and if so, in what circumstances this might be useful
- or if the type variable `r`has to be read as *for all `r`* and restricting the type of `r` will lead to all sorts of trouble.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Did you mean to make `y` a continuation as well? If it was, you could just pass the "post-processing" along into that. With explicit continuation passing, it could look like `let c1 :: Int -> Cont r Int; c1 x = let y k2 = k2 (2*x) in cont $ \k -> y (k . (+1))`.

Comment: If not, then what about just `let c1 :: Int -> Cont r Int; c1 x = let y = 2*x in return (y + 1)`?

Comment: Compare `newtype ContT r m a = ContT { runContT :: (a -> m r) -> m r }` with `newtype Codensity m a = Codensity { runCodensity :: forall r. (a -> m r) -> m r }`. The latter quantifies `r` at a _higher rank_ - that is to say, the `Codensity` computation is not allowed to assume anything about `r` and must treat it parametrically. `ContT` can do whatever the hell it wants with `r`, but `Codensity` can't.

Comment: @David Young: (1) My question is not about possible ways to do post-processing, but whether it is unreasonable.  

(2) Aren't you applying `(+1)` _before_ you call the continuation? That would be pre-processing and not much different from just adding it to the formula as in `c1 x = let y = 2*x + 1`-

Answer (score 2):

Technically, I think it's fine.  Specializing `Cont r a` to `Num r => Cont r a` doesn't seem fundamentally more problematic than specializing `Reader r a` to `Num r => Reader r a`.

An implication of doing so is that the resulting CPS computation can only be run against a (final) continuation that produces a number, but that's obvious -- if you have a computation that post-processes the continuation result as a number, it can only be used with continuations that produce numbers!

As additional evidence that this is sanctioned at least to some degree, note that there's a function:

```
mapCont :: (r -> r) -> Cont r a -> Cont r a
```

If this function was to be used with no restriction on `r`, the only valid values for its first argument would be `id` or functions that don't terminate, as you have noted.

A version of your `c1` using `mapCont` might look like:

```
c2 :: (Num r) => Int -> Cont r Int
c2 x = mapCont (+1) $ return (2*x)
```

and seems to work fine:

```
> runCont (c2 10) id
21
> runCont (c2 10) (const 5)
6
> runCont (c2 10) show
... No instance for (Num String) arising from a use of 'c2' ...
```

As for when this would be *useful*, I'm not sure.  I can think of a few somewhat lame applications.  You could define an computation that overrides the final result (provided no other kind of post-processing is used):

```
override x = cont (const x)
```

to be used like:

```
> runCont (return 2 >>= \x -> cont (\f -> f (x*3))) id
6
> runCont (return 2 >> override 1000 >>= \x -> cont (\f -> f (x*3))) id
1000
>
```

or a computation transformer that emulates a writer to add log functionality:

```
annotate note comp = mapCont (\(a, w) -> (a, note:w)) comp
```

which you might use like this:

```
runCont (annotate "two" (return 2)
        >>= \x -> annotate "times three" (cont (\f -> f (x*3))))
   (\a -> (a, []))
```

yielding:

```
(6,["two","times three"])
```

These don't seem like very compelling applications, though.

Comment: So is it correct to say that *usually* the result of the continuation is the final result? At least this is in line with the idea, that the continuation is the *rest of the computation*. While the Cont type does not say "thou shalt not not post-process", post-processing in this manner is not really popular. I believe CallCC allows doing comparable things, i.e. continue were you left off. Is this about right?

Comment: You can generalize `Cont` to `Cont f r a = (a -> r) -> f `. A `Cont f r a` represents a computation that produces `f`, but it has a hole so it can only get up to an `a`, needing help to make `r`, which it post processes to `f`. This lets you write e.g. `filtering :: [a] -> Cont a Bool [a]`. In Haskell, this is useless, because this `Cont` isn't a `Monad`, so there's no nice way to use `filtering`. In, say, Scala + `scala-continuations`, a code-rewriting compiler phase is used so you can write `reset { filtering(xs) % 2 == 0 }`. Post processing works, but looks ugly in Haskell, so it's avoided.

Answer (score 0):

@KABuhr has shown that post-processing in the ordinary `Cont` works, but didn't find "very compelling applications". I'm going to show you how post-processing *is* useful, but it only works best when you generalize `Cont`. First, some header stuff (mostly used in the examples):

```
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}

import Prelude(Num(..), Eq(..), Enum(..))
import Data.Bool
import Data.Function
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Tuple

import Control.Lens(_1, _2, traversed)
```

Now, a generalized `Cont`.

```
newtype Cont r f a = Cont { runCont :: (a -> r) -> f }
```

Your question was "is post-processing allowed in `Cont`?" The answer is yes. If would like it to not be so, you can use `newtype ContS a = { runContS :: forall r. (a -> r) -> r }` which totally disallows it. In fact, `ContS a` is isomorphic to `a`. The `Cont` I just defined takes the opposite position: even type-changing post-processors are allowed. We can define a standard `Functor`ial `(<$>)`.

```
infixl 1 <$>
(<$>) :: (a -> b) -> Cont r f a -> Cont r f b
f <$> Cont x = Cont $ \cont -> x $ \realX -> cont (f realX)
```

Before continuing, let's get an understanding of the metaphor behind `Cont`. A `Cont r f a` is a computation that can produce `a`s. It will give you the `a`s, but will ask you to produce `r`s. Once you do that, it'll make `f`s. It's sort of like a `(r -> f, a)`, but with heavy restrictions on use. If we try to define an `Applicative`-ish operator, we see something interesting.

```
infixl 1 <*> 
(<*>) :: Cont m f (a -> b) -> Cont r m a -> Cont r f b
Cont f <*> Cont x = Cont $ \cont -> x $ \realX -> f $ \realF -> cont (realF realX)
```

`(<*>)` is sort of doing two operations at once. It is applying the `a -> b` to an `a` to get `b`, but it's also composing the `m -> f` and `r -> m` aspects into a `r -> f` part. However, the type of `(<*>)` no longer fits into the normal `Applicative` format. This is why we use `Cont r a` instead of `Cont r f a`. The former is less powerful, but it fits into our existing framework. To get our `Cont` to work, we have to leave some of the established infrastructure behind.

Before we get into the `RebindableSyntax`-level stuff, here's some usage.

```
complete :: Cont a f a -> f
complete (Cont x) = x id

amb :: [a] -> Cont (Maybe b) (Maybe (a, b)) a
amb [] = Cont (const Nothing)
amb (x : xs) = Cont $ \test -> case test x of
                                    Nothing -> runCont (amb xs) test
                                    Just y -> Just (x, y)
poly :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> a
poly x y z = sq x * y + sq y + z + sq z * x
    where sq x = x * x
solution :: (Num a, Enum a, Eq a) => Maybe (a, (a, (a, ())))
solution = complete $ testRoot <$> amb [-5..5]
                               <*> amb [-10 .. -5]
                               <*> amb [5..10]
    where testRoot x y z = case poly x y z of
                                0 -> Just ()
                                _ -> Nothing
```

`complete` completes a computation when there isn't actually a gap holding it up. `amb` takes a `[a]`, and goes through each `a`, one by one. It passes each into the `test`, and searches until it finds one that succeeds. It post-processes the result of the `test` in two ways. It resets the result until it's a `Just` (or gives up), and a `Just` result gets up paired with the input that built it.

In `solution`, the `complete` is delimiting the extent of the continuation passed to the `amb`s. Each `amb` is passed the code that lies between it and the `complete`. E.g., the continuation given to the `amb [-5..5]` is `\x -> testRoot x <*> amb [-10 .. -5] <*> amb [10..5]`. This style of continuations is called `shift`/`reset`. `Cont` is `shift`, `complete` is `reset`. The idea is that `amb [-5..5]` is a "liar"; it "looks like" a `Num a => a` because it's getting passed to `testRoot`, but it's actually a control structure that turns everything around it inside-out. Compared to the normal `Cont r a`, the control structures allowed in our `Cont` are more powerful.

Now, here's what we need `RebindableSyntax` for:

```
(=<<) :: (a -> Cont r m b) -> Cont m f a -> Cont r f b
f =<< Cont x = Cont $ \cont -> x $ \realX -> runCont (f realX) cont
(>>=) = flip (=<<)
return :: a -> Cont r r a
return x = Cont ($ x)
```

`(=<<)` is the `Monad`-style function application operator. Again, our version doesn't fit the usual type. With `(>>=)` and `return`, `do`-notation has now been redefined to work with `Cont`. You can go back and rewrite `solution` in `do`-notation to see that it works.

Let's really get out there. The idea behind profunctor optics is that data structures give rise to "transformer transformers". E.g. a `Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t` takes a transformer between the "small" structures `a` and `b` and makes one from between the "bigger" `s` and `t`. Look what lies just a `flip` away...

```
editing :: ((a -> Identity b) -> s -> Identity t) -> s -> Cont b t a
editing optic x = Cont (runIdentity . flip optic x . (Identity .))
```

`editing`, as a control structure, takes a reference to a field inside a structure, a structure to use it on, and then mutates that structure with "the rest of the program." Using it, you can write the following:

```
example :: (a -> a) -> [(Bool, (a, a))] -> [(Bool, (a, a))]
example f xs = complete $ do x <- editing traversed xs
                             n2 <- editing _2 x
                             n <- case fst x of
                                       True -> editing _1 n2
                                       False -> editing _2 n2
                             return (f n)
```

I hope, with even these contrived examples, that you're convinced that post-processing is useful in `Cont`. There's nothing wrong with doing it. However, if you want to use it at its full potential, you have to break out of the existing `Applicative` and `Monad` form. This is painful, so we cripple `Cont` to make it fit, disabling type-changing post-processing as a trade-off.